# When i sudo npm install exec-sync occurred

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

version info

> node-gyp : v2.0.2
>
> npm : v2.13.4
>
> node : v0.12.7

When i sudo npm install exec-sync occurred

$ sudo npm install exec-sync

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.4.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Nealkim/Work/dev/src/TobeSmart/node_modules/exec-sync/node_modules/ffi
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "exec-sync"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! ffi@1.2.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ffi@1.2.5 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ffi package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ffi
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Nealkim/Work/dev/src/TobeSmart/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Please add some context to your question instead of just an error dump.

Comment: ok, added version info.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92 discusses why `sudo` should never be used with `npm`. It addresses the security risk, and the problem of the forced install not belonging to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this on ubuntu by doing and apt-get install:

```
apt-get install node-gyp
```